# How to read a REG_BINARY value from registry where installations of 32bit applications are found, but on a 64bit OS using C#

Tags: c#, registry

I want to get the value of this particular node in the registry using C# on a Win7 64bit machine:

[image]

This value resides in the registry where installations of 32bit applications store their information. The problem I am facing is not reaching the node but returning a meaningful value as array (string or int).

The code I am using is shown below and is adapted from

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/378491d6-23a3-4ae7-a702-c52c5abb0e8d/access-to-both-32-and-64-bit-registry-using-c-and-regmultisz?forum=csharpgeneral

and

http://www.rhyous.com/2011/01/24/how-read-the-64-bit-registry-from-a-32-bit-application-or-vice-versa/

So my listing is this:

```
public static UIntPtr HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = new UIntPtr(0x80000002u);

[DllImport("Advapi32.dll")]
public static extern int RegQueryValueEx(int hKey, string lpValueName, int lpReserved, ref uint lpType, byte[] lpData, ref uint lpcbData);

public enum RegSAM
{
    QueryValue = 0x0001,
    SetValue = 0x0002,
    CreateSubKey = 0x0004,
    EnumerateSubKeys = 0x0008,
    Notify = 0x0010,
    CreateLink = 0x0020,
    WOW64_32Key = 0x0200,
    WOW64_64Key = 0x0100,
    WOW64_Res = 0x0300,
    Read = 0x00020019,
    Write = 0x00020006,
    Execute = 0x00020019,
    AllAccess = 0x000f003f
}

string path = @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion";

RegistryKey rkTest = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(path);
try
{   
    int hkey = 0;
    uint lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, path, 0, (int)RegSAM.QueryValue | (int)RegSAM.WOW64_32Key, out hkey);
    if (0 != lResult) hkey = 0;
    else
    {
        uint lpType = 0;
        uint lpcbData = 1024;
        byte[] Buffer = new Byte[1024];
        RegQueryValueEx(hkey, "DigitalProductID", 0, ref lpType, Buffer, ref lpcbData);
        ... at this point the buffer returns empty.
    }
}
catch (Exception exc) { };
```

but my when I execute it my buffer is empty.

[image]

The code that I have provided here can reach that particular location the registry shown in the top image and read normal string values if I replace byte[] with the StringBuilder class, provided the value in the registry is of type REG_SZ. But what can we do if it is of type REG_BINARY?

Could somebody point out to me how can I achieve this?

PS:

Just to show that I have been working on a similar issue for a few days now I have successfully converted a REG_BINARY value into a readable array of integers from the registry using the code snippet below, but only if that value is under the WOW6432 node.

```
byte[] bytes = (byte[])rkTest.GetValue("DigitalProductID");
string s = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes);
List<int> int_array = new List<int>();
int temp_int = 0, i = 0;
for (i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++) { temp_int = bytes[i]; int_array.Add(temp_int); }
```

The problem I want to solve here is for that area in the registry where 32bit applications stored their information in REG_BINARY type.

Thank you.

Comment: You've got it backwards, you need the 64-bit registry view.  Change the platform target setting on your EXE project to AnyCPU (Prefer 32-bit off) or use RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey() to select the view.

Comment: Hi Hans, thanks for the effort, you had a point suggesting the use of OpenBaseKey(), the 2nd link shows the solution I needed. Had it not been at the bottom of the page I would have probably got it sooner! It is not as straightforward at all as simply putting a few lines of code to achieve what I wanted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Apparently the 2nd link I provided had exactly what I needed at the last example shown on that page. To adapt that solution in my code all I had to do add method GetRegKey64AsByteArray() like this:

```
static public byte[] GetRegKey64AsByteArray(UIntPtr inHive, String inKeyName, RegSAM in32or64key, String inPropertyName)
{
    int hkey = 0;
    try {
        uint lResult = RegOpenKeyEx(inHive, inKeyName, 0, (int)RegSAM.QueryValue | (int)in32or64key, out hkey);
        if (0 != lResult) return null;
        RegistryValueKind lpType = 0;
        uint lpcbData = 2048;
        // Just make a big buffer the first time
        byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[1000];
        // The first time, get the real size
        RegQueryValueEx(hkey, inPropertyName, 0, ref lpType, byteBuffer, ref lpcbData);
        // Now create a correctly sized buffer
        byteBuffer = new byte[lpcbData];
        // now get the real value
        RegQueryValueEx(hkey, inPropertyName, 0, ref lpType, byteBuffer, ref lpcbData);
        return byteBuffer;  
    }
    finally { if (0 != hkey) RegCloseKey(hkey); }
}
```

and then get the REG_BINARY code in a string like so:

```
byte[] byteValue64 = new byte[1024];
RegistryKey localKey = Registry.LocalMachine;
localKey = localKey.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion");
if (localKey != null)
{
    byteValue64 = GetRegKey64AsByteArray(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, @"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion", RegSAM.WOW64_64Key, "DigitalProductID");
    string s = Convert.ToBase64String(byteValue64);
    //Need to do the following operation because array returns inverted!
    List<int> int_array = new List<int>();
    int temp_int = 0, i = 0;                
    for (i = 0; i < byteValue64.Length; i++) { temp_int = byteValue64[i]; int_array.Add(temp_int); }
    ... do something with the INT values here
}
```

At the last line I am sending the INT array to a function which gives me a readable alphanumeric string.

Thanks everyone.

Comment: If you've found the solution, you should post that as an answer. Don't put it in the question and then add a "blank" answer linking back to the question. That's just messy. If you put it in the answer, you can then accept the answer for future visitors with the same problem.

Comment: Thanks @mhlester I followed your advice.